# How to calculate the number of zeros in binary?

Tags: java, binary

Hi I am making a method that can take an integer as a parameter and compute how many zeros its binary form has. So for example, if I have binaryZeros(44), its binary form is 101100. Therefore, binaryZeros(44) should return 3. However, I am making some errors and I cannot tell where it is coming from. I would appreciate it if someone can point out where I am making that error, or if my approach (logic) to this problem is good enough. Thank you!
My code is Below:

```
public static int binaryZeros(int n) {
int zeroCount = 0;
double m = n;
while (m >= 0.0) {
    m = m / 2.0;
    if (m == Math.floor(m)) {
        zeroCount++;
    } else {
        m = Math.floor(m);
    }
}
return zeroCount;
}
```

Comment: When you run this using a debugger, what is the *first* thing it does incorrectly?

Comment: The condition inside the while loop will always trigger. m will never become lower than 0

Comment: You need to change your conditional to `(m  > 0.0)`.  And since you are comparing to 0, your method won't handle negative numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Below is a more concise way to solve this problem

```
public static int binaryZeros(int n) {
    int zeroCount = 0;
    
    // Run a while loop until n is greater than or equals to 1
    while(n >= 1)
    {
        /* Use modulo operator to get the reminder of division by 2 (reminder will be 1 or 0 as you are dividing by 2). 
           Keep in mind that binary representation is an array of these reminders until the number is equal to 1. 
           And once the number is equal to 1 the reminder is 1, so you can exit the loop there.*/ 
        if(n % 2 == 0)
        {
            zeroCount++;
        }

        n = n / 2;
    }
    return zeroCount;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is good, but I think there's a better way to do it. The Integer class has a static method that returns the binary of a number: `Integer.toBinaryString(num)` . This will return a String.
Then, you can just check if there are any 0 in that string with method that has a for loop and evaluating with an if:

```
public int getZeros(String binaryString){
int zeros = 0;
for(int i=0; i < binaryString.length; i++)
      if(binaryString.charAt[i].equals('0')
           zeros++;
return zeros;
}
```

I believe this would be a simpler option and it doesn't have any errors.

Comment: There is a shorter (but less efficient) way, which is to use String.replace with a regex that takes out the 1's. It's just String.length() on the result

Comment: Correct, that would be another possible approach.

Answer (score 1):

Once `m == 0.0`, it will never change, so your `while` loop will never stop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. It simply complements the integer reversing 1's and 0's and then counts the 1 bits.  You should not be using floating point math when doing this.

- `~` complements the bits
- `&1` masks the low order bit. Is either 1 or 0
- `>>>` shifts right 1 bit including sign bit.

```
System.out.println(binaryZeros(44) + " (" +Integer.toBinaryString(44) +")"); 
System.out.println(binaryZeros(-44) + " ("Integer.toBinaryString(-44)+")");
            
public static int binaryZeros(int v) {
    int count = 0;
    while (v != 0) {
        // count 1 bits 
        // of ~v
        count += (~v)&1;
        v >>>=1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Prints

```
3 (101100)
4 (11111111111111111111111111010100)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getZeros(int num) {
        String str= Integer.toBinaryString(num);
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
            if(str.charAt(i)=='0') count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

The method toBinaryString()  returns a string representation of the integer argument as an unsigned integer in base 2. It accepts an argument in Int data-type and returns the corresponding binary string.
Then the for loop counts the number of zeros in the String and returns it.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a number m >= 0, it can never become negative no matter how many times you divide it by 2 or use Math.floor. The loop should stop when m reaches 0, so change the condition to `while (m > 0.0)`.

Note that you could do the same thing with built-in standard library methods. For example, there is a method that returns the number of leading zeros in a number, and a method that returns the number of bits set to 1. Using both you can compute the number of zeros that are not leading zeros:

```
static int binaryZeros(int n) {
    return Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n) - Integer.bitCount(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just be simple, whe there's `Integer.bitCount(n)` method:

```
public static int binaryZeros(int n) {
    long val = n & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
    int totalBits = (int)(Math.log(val) / Math.log(2) + 1);
    int setBits = Long.bitCount(val);
    return totalBits - setBits;
}
```